# Warning dst_ is no longer being supported in NS. dst_ 0xffffffff

Tags: ns2

I'm try to configure leach in ns2.35 at ubuntu 14.04 following [this](http://www.nsnam.com/2015/05/leach-protocol-installation-in-ns2-ns.html)
When I run the ./leach_test, in the /mit/leach_sims/leach.out show the result like this.

```
Creating sensor nodes...
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 
73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 
96 97 98 99 (100 == BS)
*** NOTE: no connection pattern specified.
Loading scenario file...
Node 0: (65.745973803916002,92.581722416254564)
...
...
Node 98: (2.466682112993059,57.526273074339272)
Node 99: (44.071560420129238,10.71598111219517)
Max Distance for this Simulation is 139.0
Load complete...
Starting Simulation...
THRESH = 0.050000000000000003
0: *******************************************
THRESH = 0.050000000000000003
..
..
8: *******************************************
8: Is a cluster head at time 0
THRESH = 0.050000000000000003
..
..
95: *******************************************
95: Is a cluster head at time 0
THRESH = 0.050000000000000003
96: *******************************************
THRESH = 0.050000000000000003
..
..
Warning dst_ is no longer being supported in NS. dst_ 0xffffffff
Use dst_addr_ and dst_port_ instead
..
..
0: Current cluster-head is 8, code is 1,  dist is 43
1: Current cluster-head is 8, code is 1,  dist is 66
..
..
95: Current cluster-head is 95, code is 1,  dist is 139.0
96: Current cluster-head is 8, code is 1,  dist is 54
..
..
Warning dst_ is no longer being supported in NS. dst_ 0xffffffff
Use dst_addr_ and dst_port_ instead
Warning dst_ is no longer being supported in NS. dst_ 0xffffffff
Use dst_addr_ and dst_port_ instead
Warning!  There are no nodes in this cluster (53)!
Data being sent to the Base Station
Data was sent to the base station
Warning!  There are no nodes in this cluster (95)!
Data being sent to the Base Station
Data was sent to the base station
Warning dst_ is no longer being supported in NS. dst_ 0xffffffff
Use dst_addr_ and dst_port_ instead
num_nodes is set 101
channel.cc:sendUp - Calc highestAntennaZ_ and distCST_
highestAntennaZ_ = 1.5,  distCST_ = 222.8
```

Can someone tell me what still happen?

```
Warning dst_ is no longer being supported in NS. dst_ 0xffffffff 
Use dst_addr_ and dst_port_ instead

Warning!  There are no nodes in this cluster (53)!
Data being sent to the Base Station
Data was sent to the base station" ?
```

Or can someone give me suggestion or his story what version of ns and ubuntu or the way that can I use so the leach protocol can running well?

Thank you very much..

Comment: Your result looks to be OK. .... What is it that you think isn't OK ? ? INFO, leach http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/issue-in-leach-protocol-installation-invalid-command-name-resource-energy-4175556129/#11 ... and post #9

Comment: "Irrelevant" warnings, and general warnings are not errors. Warnings are informational text.

Comment: Thank you @KnudLarsen..
I'm newbie in leach protocol and NS2